# How to create and configure a base docker images from iso

Tags: docker

I miserably failed to find any sound instructions on how to do that. All I've tried so far was of no effect. Here's the best I could do:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso rootfs
$ cd rootsfs
$ sudo tar -c . | sudo docker import - ubuntuserver
```

It does create an image but here is the thing, the `sudo docker image inspect ubuntuserver` returns a somewhat empty config. I would really like to change a whole lot of things there, but I could not. I've managed to change some fields with the help of `docker import --change` but not all of them. I've also tried opening the json in the text editor and editing it but after I save the file , the docker image becomes invisible and is no longer displayed by the `docker images` command.

If I try to create a container from the image like so:

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntuserver /bin/bash
```

I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

But seems like it's obviously because the image is not configured properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a tool such as [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) which allows to create a debian like base system.

According to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#create-a-full-image-using-tar):

> It can be as simple as this to create an Ubuntu parent image:

```
$ sudo debootstrap xenial xenial > /dev/null
$ sudo tar -C xenial -c . | docker import - xenial

a29c15f1bf7a

$ docker run xenial cat /etc/lsb-release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
```

Comment: Yeah I've seen it but did not try though. Prolly cos it's no universal. However I've run the first command with bionic instead of xenial, cos that's the distro I'm running. It's been executing for 10 mins already. And what about those env vars below the docker command? Should I set them manually or something? Or it's the output of the above command?

Comment: I'mm getting the following errors: `tar: ./sys/module/drm/uevent: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: ./proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: ./proc/sys/net/ipv6/route/flush: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: ./proc/sys/vm/compact_memory: Cannot open: Permission denied`

Comment: Did you use `sudo`?

Comment: Yes I do indeed.

Comment: I've finally found out what was wrong, I'd recommend that one should run the first command without the `> /dev/null` part cos otherwise you don't see how's the installation progressing.